# text selection handles webview android chromium

Tags: android, text, webview, selection, chromium

I understand that we cannot get the left / right handles into our control to manipulate them such as change of color or images of left / right handles. Anyone know how to get the control of these left / right handles into our control ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, we tried calling getSelectedText(), it gives selected text string, and we thought we can get the start / end handles by using startSelection / endSelection but no success. Any suggestion?